# Minor DIR error

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

# When a match is not found, just present nothing.
shopt -s nullglob

# Match all .wav files containing the date format.
files=(*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*.wav)

if [[ ${#files[@]} -eq 0 ]]; then
 echo "No match found."
fi

for file in "${files[@]}"; do
 # We get the date part by part
 file_date=''
 # Sleep it to parts.
 IFS="-." read -ra parts <<< "$file"
 for t in "${parts[@]}"; do
        # Break from the loop if a match is found
    if [[ $t == [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ]]; then
        file_date=$t
        break
     fi
  done
 # If a value was not assigned, then show an error message and continue to the next file.
 # Just making sure there is nothing in Array and date before it moves on
 if [[ -z $file_date ]]; then
    unset $files
    continue
fi

file_year=${file_date:0:4}
file_month=${file_date:4:2}

echo $file_year
echo $file_month
echo mkdir -p $file_year/$file_month
mkdir -p "$file_year/$file_month"

 # -- is just there to not interpret filenames starting with - as options.

echo "$file" "$file_year/$file_month" 
mv  "$file" "$file_year/$file_month"
done
```

So after running my code my output is this I det DIR 201211, 201212, 201301,201302,201303,201304, So I try running this because I have files that have a YYYYMMDD and wanna make DIR the year and then inside that i want DIR month then file. Sometimes I can get a DIR2013/06/files but for some odd reason i get DIR201304/files. I am not understanding what the issue is....... Im running this script on about 1.1 Terabite

Comment: You need to unset a variable *name* not a variable's *value*: `unset files`. However, unsetting the value will not terminate the loop: you have already expanded the array into words, that that's what the for loop is iterating over. You should `break` instead.

Comment: So instead of unset you want me to use break then continue ?

Comment: On second thought, I don't understand the purpose of that code. Why are you unsetting?

Comment: Well i do not know why it would work have the time doing 2013/01 , 2013/02/"files" then does 2012/01/"files" like i want but after a while it does 201202/"files", 201309/"files"

Comment: I can't see why you code shouldn't work. Add `set -x` to the top of your script to see exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

bash can do regular expressions, so you can do something like this:

```
filename="blah.blah-12345678.ext"
if [[ $filename =~ [.-]([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})[0-9]{2}[.-] ]]; then 
    echo year=${BASH_REMATCH[1]} month=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
fi
```

```
year=1234 month=56
```

`BASH_REMATCH` is an array holding the matched part of the string in index 0 and other indices hold the parts captured by parentheses.